# Removing duplicate error handling code Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, callback

I have duplicated error handling code in my Node.js code, how can I make it better to get rid of duplicated code. I specifically want to ask error handling about this callback way, not the Promise way.

```
var request = require('request');
var URL = 'http://localhost:3000';

var getRanking = function get_rank(error, response, body) {
   if (error) {
        handleError(error);
   } else {         
       if (response.statusCode != 200) {
          handleError(response);
       } else {        
          console.log('Response 1 ' + body);
          request(URL + '/iso/country/' + JSON.parse(body).Country, getISO);
       }
   }
}

var getISO = function get_iso(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
         handleError(error);          
    } else {
        if (response.statusCode != 200) {
             handleError(response)
        } else {
             console.log("Response 2 "+body);
             request(URL+'/olympic/2016/medal/'+JSON.parse(body).iso,getMedalCount);
        }
    } 
}

var getMedalCount = function get_medal_count(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
       handleError(error);
    } else {
       if (response.statusCode != 200) {
           handleError(response);
       } else {        
           console.log("Response 3 " + body);
       }
    }  
}

function handleError(err) {
   console.log('Error ' + JSON.stringify(err))
}

request(URL+'/olympic/2016/ranking/4', getRanking);
```

Comment: Can you point exactly, what duplicates you want to avoid?

Comment: You mean you 'handleError' twice in each function?

Comment: you can throw the `error` and catch it.

So it would be like:

    try {
        request(URL+'/olympic/2016/ranking/4', getRanking);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

Comment: @Lazyexpert I understand that we can check for both error and response.statusCode and then call handleError. It will remove some extra lines, other than that can I make the code any better

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
var request = require('request');
var URL = 'http://localhost:3000';

var getRanking = function get_rank(error, response, body) {
   if (error) {
        throw error;
   }
   if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        throw new Error(response);
   }      
   console.log('Response 1 ' + body);
   request(URL + '/iso/country/' + JSON.parse(body).Country, getISO);
}

var getISO = function get_iso(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        throw new Error(response);
    }
    console.log("Response 2 "+body);
    request(URL+'/olympic/2016/medal/'+JSON.parse(body).iso,getMedalCount);
    } 
}

var getMedalCount = function get_medal_count(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }        
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
       throw new Error(response);
        return;
   }
   console.log("Response 3 " + body);
}

try {
    request(URL+'/olympic/2016/ranking/4', getRanking);
} catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way to shorten your code would probably be the following :

```
function handleError(err, res) {
   if(err){
     console.log('Error '+JSON.stringify(err));
     return false;
   } else if(res.statusCode != 200) {
     console.log('Error '+JSON.stringify(res));
     return false;
   } else {
     return true;
   }
}

// and then, use it in your functions like that : 
var getRanking = function get_rank(error,response,body) {
  if (handleError(err, res)) { // if there is no error, do your stuff   
     console.log("Response 1 "+body);
     request(URL+'/iso/country/'+JSON.parse(body).Country,getISO);
   }
}
```

But I think that's not very appropriate to JS, because JS can be used as a functional programming language (which is better) and this approach looks more procedural (like C language).
**So, in my opinion, the below solution would be proper :**

```
function handleError(successFunc) {
  return function (error, response, body) { 
    if (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    } else if(response.statusCode != 200) {
      throw new Error(response);
    } else {
      successFunc(response);
    }
  }
}

// then, just pass your successFunc to your error handler :


var getRanking = function (response) {
  // do your success stuff.
}
try {
  request(URL+'/olympic/2016/ranking/4', handleError(getRanking));
} catch (e) {
  // catch your error here
}
```

If your request is a success, `getRanking` will be executed, if this is a failure, the error will be logged and thrown.

With this solution, you can pass any function to your error handler and it will be used if the request succeed, if the request fails, the error handler will `throw` an error and then, you will be able to `catch` it.

Hope it helps,
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Create a funciton `handleResponse` and write the `response handling duplicated code` in that funciton.

Call that `function` with `required parameters` as given,

```
var request = require('request');
var URL = 'http://localhost:3000';

var getRanking = function get_rank(error, response, body) {
   handleResponse(error, response, body, 'getISO');
}

var getISO = function get_iso(error, response, body) {
    handleResponse(error, response, body, 'getMedalCount');
}

var getMedalCount = function get_medal_count(error, response, body) {
    handleResponse(error, response, body null);
}

function handleResponse(error, response, body, url) {
   if (error) {
        handleError(error);
   } else {         
       if (response.statusCode != 200) {
          handleError(response);
       } else {
            if(url == 'getISO')        
            {
                request(URL + '/iso/country/' + JSON.parse(body).Country, getISO);
            }
            else if(url == 'getMedalCount')
            {
                request(URL+'/olympic/2016/medal/'+JSON.parse(body).iso,getMedalCount);
            }
       }
   }
}

function handleError(err) {
   console.log('Error ' + JSON.stringify(err))
}

request(URL+'/olympic/2016/ranking/4', getRanking);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as far as noone suggested such optimization, I will.
Instead of such block:

```
if (error) {
  handleError(error);
} else {
  if (response.statusCode != 200) {
    handleError(response);
  } else {        
    console.log("Response 3 " + body);
  }
}
```

You can do this way:

```
if (error || response.statusCode != 200) handlerError(error || response);
else console.log("Response 3 " + body);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to handle response.

```
var request = require('request');
var URL     = "http://localhost:3000";


var getRanking = function get_rank (body) {
    console.log("Response 1 " + body);
    request(URL + '/iso/country/' + JSON.parse(body).Country, handleResponse.bind(null, getISO));
}

var getISO = function get_iso (body) {
    console.log("Response 2 " + body);
    request(URL + '/olympic/2016/medal/' + JSON.parse(body).iso, handleResponse.bind(null, getMedalCount));
}


var getMedalCount = function get_medal_count (body) {
    console.log("Response 3 " + body);
}

function handleResponse (callback, error, response, body) {
    console.log(error, response, body, callback)
    if (error || response.statusCode != 200) {
        console.log('Error ' + JSON.stringify(error))
    }
    else {
        callback(body);
    }
}

request(URL + '/olympic/2016/ranking/4', handleResponse.bind(null, getRanking));
```